# Javascript writing if statements to prompt user for input

Tags: javascript

```
var noun;
var verb;
var adverb;
var adjective;
var pronoun;
var questions = 5; //this number can adjust
var paragraph;

var noun = prompt("Type Noun");
if (isNaN(noun) == "True"){
 questions -= 1;
 verb = prompt("Type Verb");
}else{
   alert("You entered a number, please enter a Noun.");
}
if (isNaN(verb) == "True"){
 questions -= 1;
 adverb = prompt("Type Adverb");
}else{
   alert("You entered a number, please enter a Verb.");
}
if (isNaN(adverb) == "True"){
 questions -= 1;
 adjective = prompt("Type Adjective");
}else{
   alert("You entered a number, please enter a Adverb.");
}
if (isNaN(pronoun) == "True"){
 questions -= 1;
}else{
   alert("You entered a number, please enter a Pronoun.");
}
```

So the main idea is to have the user input a word. 
For some reason it marks the boolean false and goes directly into the else statement.....

Comment: Which boolean does it mark as false?

Comment: As it iterates through each one, so the initial one was marked false. Then it skips to each else statement, skipping the if statement.

Comment: what is the requirement & expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because isNaN("some text") returns a boolean true/false -- and true == "True" returns false. Your statements should read:

```
if (isNaN(noun) === true) {
}
....
```